# Ubuntu 10 Ruby 1.9 Rails 3: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rvm

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now. I'm running Ubuntu 10 on the dev machine which had ruby **1.8** on it, which I **removed**. I **installed Ruby 1.9.3** and rails3 using **RVM** and this tutorial http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

---

when I type `ruby -v` I get

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]
```

which seems correct.

I created a new test app using

```
rails new mysite
```

which created the new app successfully.
then I

```
cd mysite
```

and created a gemset

```
rvm gemset create 'rails3'
```

then I used this inside the /mysite/ folder

```
rvm use 1.9.3@rails3 --rvmr
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125 with gemset rails3
```

**but the problem arises when I try to run it**

```
root@server-pc:/var/www/mysite# rails s
-bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

EDIT1:

```
root@server-pc:/var/www/mysite# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running ruby you installed with RVM?
Did you installed rvm on your user folder? (you shouldn't have installed it in root).
Check where your ruby is installed (which ruby)
Should be somewhere like this: "/home/user/"your user"/.rvm/..."

Comment: so how should I go about this then, uninstall rvm and install as a non root user?

Comment: Thats what I do and as far as I know any other ruby developer. Just use steps here: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Also if you did installed ruby on root be sure that you don't install there again. Finally don't forget to use command "rvm use 1.9.3" everytime.

Comment: @AyJay ok Ill give it a go, will let you know in a couple of minutes

Comment: ok I did a reinstall of rvm and ruby 1.9 and rails but when I type `rails new mysite2` it shows the same error --> `server@server-pc:/var/www$ rails new mysite2
-bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try "bundle install" and then "bundle exec rails new mysite2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*log in as **root user***

### ---

### remove old ruby

list ruby packeges

```
dpkg -l | grep ruby
```

then remove all ruby packeges

```
aptitude purge <package name>
```

if you have rvm installed

```
rvm remove all
```

then

```
rvm implode
```

or

```
rvmsudo rvm implode
```

---

### install ruby

still logged in as **root**

install all of the necessary tools and libraries

```
apt-get install curl git-core build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline5-dev
```

install rvm

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Then **add** this line as the **last line** in your .bashrc:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile

if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ; fi
```

test RVM install

```
rvm notes
```

Next, you can begin ruby 1.9.2 installation by running

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

The install will take up to several minutes and once it completes you have to set ruby 1.9.2 as the default version

```
rvm --default ruby-1.9.2
```

test your new ruby install
**ruby -v**

install Rails 3

```
gem install rails
```

If you want to get a quick database up and running with sqlite, then you’ll need to sqlite3 and the libsqlite3-dev packages

```
apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev

gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

create new app

```
rails new testapp

cd testapp
```

Make sure you are in your test app directory and run

```
rails s
```

Open your browser at
http://localhost:3000

Comment: When testing      rvm notes      I had to look at where the system had pulled rvm down into (/usr/local/rvm) and then source /scripts/rvm from there in order to get the notes command to work.

Answer (score 1):

well, I believe this line:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

means that you already have a /usr/bin/rails binary which is using ruby1.8 interpreter. Try moving it somewhere:

```
mv /usr/bin/rails /usr/bin/rails-1.8
```

then go to your project directory, and `bundle install`.

if you already have the rails bundled, try reinstalling the gems.

Comment: `server@server-pc:/usr/bin$ cd rails
-bash: cd: rails: Not a directory`

Comment: it's not intended to be a directory, it's just a script. and it's using your old non-existent interpreter. so just remove it: sudo rm /usr/bin/rails

Comment: `Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.` --> `rails s
-bash: /usr/bin/rails: No such file or directory`

Comment: try: rvm gemset use @yourgemset, then `which rails`, it should show you something like: /home/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-falcon@proj/bin/rails