# ruby on rails uninstall manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uninstallation

I have big problems in uninstalling ruby in ubunty. 
I'm following https://stackoverflow.com/a/9618017/1796624 and when I try

```
aptitude purge <package name>
```

I get:

```
E: I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
E: I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
E: Internal error: couldn't generate list of packages to download
```

How to completely remove rails and ruby, where can I find the  ttf-mscorefonts-installer package and now to manually fix it ?

Comment: If you're having problems with `rails` try installing rvm.

Comment: Or rbenv (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) is good too...less intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

ttf-mscorefonts-installer - is a package for install Microsoft TrueType fonts, this package no influence on rails.
Problem in your apt-get utility.