# I get a bash error message when I run "bundle install" after re-installing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I removed the previous version of ruby I installed, ruby 1.9.1 to be precise, on my Ubuntu, and installed version 2.2.3. When I try to run bundle install on my terminal, I get this error

> bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.

Can anyone advice on how to fix it?

Comment: `gem install bundler`

Comment: try gem install bundler

Comment: Check this post [Stackoverflow][1] might help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563656/ubuntu-10-ruby-1-9-rails-3-not-working

Comment: `gem install bundler` worked perfectly. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

How did you remove the old version of Ruby?

It looks like it left the binary executable for `bundler`, so I'm guessing you just straight up deleted the `usr/bin/ruby` folder? Ruby installations (and most installations) tend to create executable binaries in other folders that need to be deleted as well.

I would **highly** recommend that you use something like `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage multiple versions of ruby on your system. Those tools are designed to do that sort of thing and are basically industry standard at this point.

My personal recommendation is `rvm`, although either is really fine. If you choose to go with that, check out rvm.io for installation instructions.

It'll install `rvm` with the latest ruby version. In addition to that you are free to install any other version of ruby or patch that you prefer, and you can easily switch between the two using `rvm use <ruby version>`

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get purge ruby1.9` to remove the previous version. I ran the `gem install bundler` and it worked well. I will still install rvm as you advised for future proposes. Thanks.